# BLE remote controller can not connected

Tags: macos, bluetooth, keyboard, bluetooth-lowenergy, mouse

I have a raspi 3 with raspbian, and today I cannot connect my BLE remote controller（it used to be able to connect）, when I run *bluetoothctl* cmd, It Will automatically display "...connected： yes or no", as shown below. But when I change my BLE remote controller's MAC to C7:E4:E3:E2:E1:66, it connected and work well, why this happen? what's wrong?
[image]

Comment: hey   there ，      Nobody?

Comment: anyone help!!!!